# How do fonts react to font-weight when those are OS fonts?

Tags: html, css, fonts, typography

Do [system UI fonts](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/issues/665) act the same way regarding font-weight ?

I tried this :

```
font-family: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif
```

and this

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500');
font-family: Roboto
```

On my ubuntu OS. The font weight didn't have the same impact on both font-family. When using `font-weight: 500` with Roboto from `google.fonts` the text was bold. When using `font-weight: 500` with the `system ui fonts` I had no bold.

So I'm wondering what's up ?

Comment: The general numeric value for _bold_ is 700. Try that and see. Also, not all fonts have a _bold_ version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numeric values for `font-weight` is `100-900`.

Generally `400` is the same as `normal` and `700` for `bold`, though this is font specific.

In your case it appears as the `font-weight` of `500` for `Roboto` is defined as *thicker* than *normal*, hence the difference.

*As a side note, not all fonts have a `bold` version.*

Comment: I wanted to target the medium at 500 between bold and regular (like robotto has). So I guess I won't have that behavior if I rely on system-ui fonts. I assume that all OS default fonts have a bold version though.

Comment: @Ced If the _system-ui_ font has a defined thickness of 500 it will work, though this is font specific. And normally, most fonts has normal and bold.